# nohup process keep shutting down

Tags: linux, command-line, php, nohup, exec

I am trying to run 10.000 processes to create asterisks phone accounts. 
This is to stress-test our Asterisk server.

I called with php an exec() function to create a Linux command.

```
nohup /usr/src/pjproject-2.3/pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --id=sip:%s@13.113.163.3 --registrar=sip:127.0.0.1:25060 --realm=* --username=%s --password=123456 --local-port=%s --null-audio --no-vad --max-calls=32 --no-tcp >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null & $(echo -ne \'\r\')"
```

Everything works perfect and the script does exactly what I am expecting.
But here comes also the next problem; after creating the 10.000 accounts, the processes are suddenly all getting killed.

**Why is this?**

Isn't it so that the nohup function keeps the processes alive?
After calling the nohup function I am also calling the disown function.

Thank you for the help

[edit]
I also tried this project with the function screen, the screen functions work like a charm, but the problem is the cpu usage. To create 10.000 screens, makes a linux server go nuts, this is why I choose for nohup.

Comment: Replace ">>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null" by ">> /tmp/pjsua.log 2>&1" and the output may tell you what happened.  What do you expect from "$(echo -ne \'\r\')" ?  Why the single " at the end of your command?

Comment: It was used to place an enter after the coded was inputted. Also tried it without it, but this didn't work either. Everything works what we want, just the processes are killed after the php file is done.

Comment: The code is running in the background.  If it needs input it'll stop.  You can provide input through "input redirection", like "<" or "<<" (before the "&" !!)

Comment: I was thinking the same, but if I run the script without php there is not a problem. I can keep it inactive for an unlimited time.

Comment: Then why complicate things?  Who's calling php and how?  Are you sure the php's exec() understands shell syntax?

Comment: It's impossible to run 10.000 account by hand. I am calling the php myself. The script has not a problem at all, the account are created, the output is shown on the screen of this. It's just after the php script is finished, it kills the processes, they don't stay in the background.

Comment: Did you try shell_exec()?

Comment: I didn’t, aren’t they the same?

Comment: No, and there's also system(). Not that it matters, php kills its children when finished. Just write a shell script to launch your 10000 programs.